# CentOS 6.3 Device eth0 does not seem to be present (Minimal non-cloned setup)

Tags: centos, ethernet

I installed CentOS 6.3 on my hardrive partition (new install...minimal install).

After successful installation, I see that eth0 was down. I looked for this file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` but did not find it.

Here's my `ifcfg-eth0` settings: **Note I had to create this file manually**

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=*
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=ETHERNET
```

This machine is connected to Ethernet (I have Windows 7 on another partition and I am able to connect to Internet with that just fine).

```
$ ifconfig -a | grep eth
```

returns no result

```
$ ethtool eth0
```

returns `Cannot get device settings : No such device...`

What can I try to get CentOS to detect eth0?

Comment: What type of device is it?  Does it show in *lspci*, as what does it get identified?  Is it USB? *lsusb* ...

Comment: device is a NIC. It does not show up in lspci. lspci returns `command not found`

Comment: Can you try to install the pciutils RPM?  Without that diagnostics may be difficult. Do you see any mention of **eth** in /var/log/syslog or the output of **dmesg**?

Comment: grep `eth` in dmesg returns nothing. Could not install pciutils as it throws me this error `PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host mirrorlist.centos.org"` ...I believe this error again may be related to NIC card not available

Comment: Try getting the RPM on another box, and move it to your centos install via e.g., USB Stick?

Comment: @tink thank you for your inputs!!...I did used a netinstall image and configured as a software development machine. Now I am able to connect to the Internet on CentOS 6.3. When I now do ifconfig -a it shows me `p128p1` interface in addition to `lo`

Comment: I could not figure out how to fix this. I downloaded the netinstall iso version and that worked like a charm.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55381/no-network-connection-in-centos-6-3-minimal-under-vmware-player

Comment: Somewhat related to this Q: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110496/cloned-linux-system-and-etc-udev-rules-d-70-persistent-net-rules/110501#110501.

Answer (score 6):

In my situation, I changed the network adapter configuration of my hypervisor after the installation of CentOS. What happened in this case is that the old interface eth0 no longer existed but a new one called eth1 did.

```
ls /sys/class/net
eth1 lo
```

I changed the network config `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to use `DEVICE=eth1` and it worked again.

Comment: Curiously, after doing some changes on HW settings of an OVF, I also ran into this situation (CentOS 6.2). My solution was to simply rename `/sys/class/net/eth1` into `/sys/class/net/eth0` and reboot. On next reboot, the interface went up normally. Not sure if that was the *right* thing to do but it fixed the issue.

Comment: I used ifcfg-up eth0 to bring eth0 back to life. In my server eth0 was present

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified this is an non-cloned setup I will assume that you are using a virtualization environment for your machine. If so, than the solution that worked for me on a Centos 5 was to simply change the network adapter type from vmxnet3 to e1000.

For me it was like this:

1. create a virtual machine in the vcenter(hypervisor).
2. click on edit on that particular machine
3. hardware -> add -> network adapter(ethernet adapter) . change the type to e1000
4. install the OS